# Why do Poisson regression and Linear regression give the same error?

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution

I use the `badhealth` data as an example, I'm modelling the number of visit (doctor) based on the health condition and the age as two features. Mean absolute error is used as the metric. I tried Poisson regression and Linear regression but both give me the same error. Also, the plot of the predicted number of visits is so different from the true plot.

This is my entire code. Where did I go wrong?

```
#install.packages('COUNT')
library(COUNT)
data("badhealth")

pois_model = glm(numvisit ~ ., family = poisson, data = badhealth)
gaus_model = glm(numvisit ~ ., family = gaussian, data = badhealth)
mean(abs(pois_model$fitted.values - badhealth$numvisit)) # MAE is 2.012771
mean(abs(gaus_model$fitted.values - badhealth$numvisit)) # MAE is 2.014618
```

This is the true plot

```
barplot(table(badhealth$numvisit))
```

[image]

And the plot from the Poisson model:

```
barplot(table(round(pois_model$fitted.values)))
```

[image]

Comment: Naturally the (marginal) collection estimated conditional means will look different from the marginal distribution of raw values. Why should they look alike?

Comment: Because I think if the model is accurate enough, then the plots should look alike or relatively similar, I think they are so different in my case.

Comment: "I think if the model is accurate enough, then the plots should look alike" Yes, it was already clear *that* you think so, I'm asking *why* you think so. (It's not the case, so understanding how you come to think so would be useful in explaining where you reasoning is mistaken). Consider this situation: what if there was only a single group. If I do a histogram of all the values in the group, does the shape of that histogram look anything like the single mean of that group?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't expect the histogram of the fitted values to match the distribution of the observed response. This is literally regression to the mean. The fitted values will have a smaller variance.

Consider that the mean absolute error is not expected to be 0. You are taking its absolute value, so it is the $\mathcal{L}_1$ loss rather than, say, the $\mathcal{L}_2$ loss usually summarized with the residual standard error. Rather, perfect prediction would be unexpected here, and that is the only case in which the MAE, MSE, (and the residual standard error) would be zero.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the number of bins, in one or the other, so they match. Or else do less rounding of the results.

Better yet, look at density plots instead. William S. Cleveland, who probably knows as much about statistical graphics as anyone on the planet, disdains histograms, saying (IIRC) that "ubiquity and longevity are no guarantees of utility" and then stating that there will be no more histograms in his book.

Comment: I'm actually modelling number of goals (association football) and I encountered this problem. To save time and make it easier to copy the code, I use the `badhealth` data as an example. But in the football data, the number of goals is only from 0 - 9 which means less bins. I also tried different rounding to the first and second decimal but the errors are still the same.

Comment: @Juan Please [edit] your question to describe the exact problem that you're trying to solve.